# Uploading comments to the Google Analytics timeline

Tags: api, analytics

In Google Analytics, you can add a comment to any timeline.

[image]

I want to upload those comments through a script.

Is there an API which allows me to do so? Couldn't find it in the Analytics Docs.

Comment: We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements. For example: An API for which programming language? What must it support? How much are you willing to pay, or must it be free?

Comment: if the api doesn't support it, you're going to have a hard time doing so without using an automated browser, which you'd have to script yourself

Comment: I'm talking about Google Analytics, not about the Analytics 360 Suite which is paid. APIs that work over HTTP are programing language independend.
@maxpleaner I don't their API supports it, I just couldn't find it.